# hide button in css for all posts from specific wordpress category

Tags: css, wordpress

I use this code to hide a button in css. It works. Is it possible to hide the button in a specific wordpress category posts?

```
div.screen-reader-text3 
{
    display:none;
}
```

any help appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Wordpress adds class to body element on category page.

If you inspect your code on category page you'll see something like this in body class:

`archive category category-skincare category-2`.

The **skincare** it is a slug of my category, in your case it will be different.

You need to copy `category-skincare` and use it in your CSS like so:

```
.category-skincare div.screen-reader-text3 {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Each page in wordpress have personal ID. If you inspect the page source via console, you can see in body this:
`<body class="home page-template-default page page-id-58">`, where page-id-58 - the unique page id.

In css it's look like that

```
 .page-id-58 div.screen-reader-text3 {display:none;}
```